# Creating Generic Command to clear values in userform

Tags: excel, vba

I am learning to create a public sub which may be used in any userforms to clear the specified values.
However, I encountered an error. `"Me."` doesn't work as the reference to the specified userform.

I have read the other post but still could not understand. How is the right way to make the reference?

Here is the current code.

In module

```
Public Sub ClrV()
Dim ctrl As Control

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    Select Case TypeName(ctrl)
        Case Is = "TextBox"
            If ctrl.Name <> "txtDate" Then ctrl.Value = ""
        Case Is = "Label"
            If ctrl.Name Like "Label*" Or ctrl.Name = "Title" Then
            Else
            ctrl.Caption = ""
            End If
    End Select
Next ctrl
End Sub
```

In Userform

```
    If Not IsDate(txtDate.Value) Then
        Cancel = True
    Else
        Call ClrV
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The `Me` command is always a reference to whatever module that code is in. So if your sub is not in the userform module then it will not work. Simply change `Me.Controls` to your userform name (eg `Userform1.Controls`) and it should remove that problem.

Comment: Yes. I am aware of that. But that would not allow me to use the public sub for any userforms that I would like. Is there a workaround for that?
Something like indirect in excel formula?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a form as `object` to public sub then iterate all control and do action as you need. Write below codes to a standard module.

```
Public Sub ClrV(frm As Object)
Dim ctrl As Control

For Each ctrl In frm.Controls
    Select Case TypeName(ctrl)
        Case Is = "TextBox"
            If ctrl.Name <> "txtDate" Then ctrl.Value = ""
        Case Is = "Label"
            If ctrl.Name Like "Label*" Or ctrl.Name = "Title" Then
            Else
            ctrl.Caption = ""
            End If
    End Select
Next ctrl
End Sub
```

Then call the sub like

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call ClrV(UserForm1)
End Sub
```

If you don't want mention `UserForm1` then pass current form by keyword `me` like-

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call ClrV(Me)
End Sub
```

Comment: This is how I have done this in the past though I target the actual control type rather than name.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things wrong with your approach.

1. In VBA, Me, is a reference to the currently executing instance of a class.  The code you are using is in a Module so the Me statement doesn't exist.  Instead you will have to use ClrV Me.
2. Even if you do pass Me to the ClrV method you will not be able to access any of the controls of the form unless you have also included a corresponding Public Property in your Userform Code.
3. The philosophy behind objects (Object Oriented Programming) is that objects manage their own internal state themselves and the user code just passes a message to the object about what they wish to have done.  In VBA this means writing a public method within the object that does the clear fields activity.
4. It may be possible to call a helper function in a module, which is eszssentially what you are trying to do, however this is bad practise as it means you cannot reuse your user form project elsewhere without also making sure that you move the helper code as well.  SO basically, it is better all round to have duplicate code in classes to avoid this problem.

The code within an object is very likely to be generic if written correctly so it is very easy to cut and paste the code from one project to another.

Here is what I think your code should look like

In module

```
deleted as it is moved to the userform code
```

In Userform Code

```
Public Sub ClrV()
Dim ctrl As Control

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    Select Case TypeName(ctrl)
        Case  "TextBox"

            If ctrl.Name <> "txtDate" Then ctrl.Value = vbnullstring

        Case "Label"

            If NOT (ctrl.Name Like "Label*" Or ctrl.Name = "Title") Then
            
                ctrl.Caption = vbnullstring

            End If

    End Select

Next ctrl

End Sub
```

Comment: Your explanation is good but if you write code in form module then you have to write same code again and again for each form.

Comment: Yes.  This is what I said in my answer.  I also said if the code was written in a generic manner then you can cut and paste is actually very little extra work for correctly written self contained form objects.